# Excel Autofilter with Date Limit

Tags: excel, date, autofilter, vba

I try to implement an easy to use Autofilter-mask for the department in my company. My intention is to make it as flexible as possible, so the employees are able administrate it without programming.

My current issue is, that they want to filter dates using inputs like: <1W, <3M, >6M, etc.

Does anybody know a possibility to add this input to the VBA autofilter method?

I have something like this in my mind:

```
filterRange.AutoFilter
filterRange.AutoFilter 'dateColumn', "<3M"
```

The best way would be, that the employees' input is directly passed to the autofilter method.

thx in advance.

Comment: Record yourself using Autofilter and applying the various preset Date Filter options like *this week, next week, previous month, next quarter, etc*. After you've gone through a few, stop the recorder and take a look at the code you generated. That should give you some ideas on what you can offer the user.

Comment: The macro record didn't help to my mind because it offers constants only.
E.g. the "xlFilterLastWeek" constant takes the previous week and not the last seven days. In addition it takes Sunday-Saturday as a week, which is not sufficient for german speaking countries.

Comment: May have to do some math based on the current date = `CInt(Now)` in VBA.  Should just be simple subtraction.  That is, `CInt(Now) - 7` for a week ago.  If you need it to go from specific days to other days, you can add additional code that processes dates and uses some of the built-in Excel date functions `EOMONTH`, etc.

Comment: I solved it in a less comfortable way. On a hidden sheet the values like "<3M" are connected with a concrete value which is passed to the autofilter function.
The cell calls the dateadd-function which returns the date in order to cover the users period.

    `Public Function getDate(interval, no)
    getDate = Format(DateAdd(interval, no, Date), "dd.mm.yyyy")
    End Function`

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer if it resolved your issue.  This helps the community and those of us looking for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in a less comfortable way. On a hidden sheet the values like "<3M" are connected with a concrete value which is passed to the autofilter function. The cell calls the dateadd-function which returns the date in order to cover the users period.

```
Public Function getDate(interval, no) 
getDate = Format(DateAdd(interval, no, Date), "dd.mm.yyyy") 
End Function
```